# Error when access folder cgi-bin

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, cgi-bin

I created an folder with name "cgi-bin" on /var/www" When I tried access this folder I receive error 403 Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/ on this server.

I try this on Virtual Machine on environment Vagrant in machine Ubuntu with apache install.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide the permissions of the folder, your `apache` config and logs.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 403 on a directory on an Apache server is usually caused by one of these three conditions:

- The Apache server has not been granted the read and execute permissions on the directory, which are needed in order for the server to read the directory listing.
- The directory contains a `.htaccess` file, but the Apache server has not been granted read access to this file.
- Directory listings are disabled in the Apache configuration, for example it could have been disabled through `Options -Indexes`

If the directory contains an `index.html` file, it will be shown instead of a directory listing. In that case the `Indexes` option and read permission on the directory are not needed, but read access on `index.html` is needed.